# Updating multiple DB tables from Datagridviews filled via function

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

Say, I have an application to get data from SQL tables:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim QRY As String
QRY = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
dt = GetData(QRY)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
QRY = "SELECT * FROM Table2"
dt = GetData(QRY)
DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Public Function GetData(ByVal QRY As String) As DataTable
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim con As New SqlConnection(connection string here)
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(QRY, con)
Try
con.Open()
adapter.Fill(dt)
con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
Return dt
End Function
End Class
```

I have no ideas how I can update tables 1 and 2 via adapter.update if DataGridView 1 and 2 changed (added row, deleted rows, edited cells). 
Or it is impossible and adapter.update knows nothing about DataGridView filled via my function?

Comment: You can use adapter.Update(dt) equivalently to how you are using adapter.Fill(dt) to change the dt contents. Once dt has become the DataSource of the DataGridView, the changes you do on it (via Update or by any other means) should be reflected in the DGV. In any case bear in mind that DGV and dt are different things and thus you might have to rely on .Refresh() to see changes; when affecting the DGV via the DataSource there might be some coordination problems (accessing items already deleted via DataSource). The safest/easiest way is performing any modification from the DGV directly.

Comment: At first I should convert a DGV back to DT and then update a DT via adapter.update? I know how to do it for a single DT and a DGV but for multiple? Should I create a few adapters?

Comment: You cannot convert "convert a DGV back to DT" they are different objects doing things completely different. A DataTable just contains information. The DGV takes information (one of the things it has, but also has an interface doing many other actions) in different ways, one of these ways is setting dt as DataSource. The contents in the DGV are affected in the contents in the DataTable change, but not inversely.

Comment: Read my previous comment and clarify your ideas a bit: firstly you have a DataTable (which you can populate row by row and column by column or by using an Adapter), whatever you do with this DataTable will not affect the DataGridView until you don't set it as DataSource. Even after doing that, there might be some "coordination problems", as explain in my original message, and thus I recommend you not even affect the dt, but the DGV directly. Once you get these ideas clear (3 different things, eventually related: adapter, dt and dgv), please tell exactly what you want.

Comment: >Once you get these ideas clear (3 different things, eventually related: adapter, dt and dgv), please tell exactly what you want.

I understood this (or just thinking that understood). 
I have 2 or more DGV (in my first message) and I want to send an updated data back to DB. I can't find the place for "adapter.update(dt). I know that i still explaining bad. Sorry about that :/

Comment: No problem. If your ideas are clear perhaps it is a communication issue. adapter.update(dt) can replace your adapter.Fill(dt) -> it updates the dt (and thus the DGV), by sending data FROM THE DB to the DT/DGV. If you want to send data FROM THE DGV to the DB, you can also use DT (in case of not changing any record from DGV itself) and you would have to write the corresponding UPDATE/INSERT INTO query (link to hefp:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301075/en-us)